# Location-picker and open-map methods in viber with node

Tags: node.js, chatbot, viber

I'm currently working on location based service in viber chatbot on Node, but either [viber docs](https://viber.github.io/docs/tools/keyboards/) are missing information or i don't understand something important.
The methods i need are `location-picker` to make a button for sharing a location with my bot and `open-map` to open a default map application for users device and display info there on pressing a button. I neither managed to find any working example of this functionality nor find any actual data on how the keyboard requests for these should look like.

I tried making an object like that:

```
"Buttons": {
  "Columns":6,
  "Rows":3,
  "ActionType": "open-map",
  "Map": {
    "Latitude": data.latitude,
    "Longitude": data.longitude
  },
  "Image": data.image
  },
```

But this returns UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning on sending it to viber.

(Of course that's not the entire keyboard object, but its 'not-working' part; if i change ActionType to "reply" and add reply text, it will work just fine)

For location-picker i tried

```
"Buttons": {
        "Columns": 6,
        "Rows": 1,
        "BgColor": "#26CF94",
        "BgLoop": true,
        "ActionType": "location-picker",
        "Text": "Share location",
},
```

But this returns UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.

From that point, the problem is obvious, something wrong with keyboard object sent, but i can't figure out what's exactly wrong. So what is the right way to do that?

p.s. I'm using viber-bot library to manage requests

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the button . The issue is with API Version. You need to specify API version while preparing message .

```
var registerMessage = new TextMessage("Please register your account to continue", registerKeyboard,undefined,undefined,undefined,3)
```

This is for text message. And i am using API Version 3 . Similarly you can do it for other types of message and other api version

Answer (score 0):

Correct:

```json
"Buttons": {
  "Columns": 6,
  "Rows": 1,
  "BgColor": "#26CF94",
  "BgLoop": true,
  "ActionType": "location-picker",
  "ActionBody" : "location",
  "Text": "Share location",
},
```

`ActionBody` - is mandatory argument!